# Is there a better way to remove a string for an array of strings in perl?

Tags: regex, arrays, perl

I have a Perl array of URLs that all contain "http://". I'd like to remove that string from each one leaving only the domain. I'm using the following `for` loop:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

### Load a test array
my @test_array = qw (http://example.com http://example.net http://example.org);

### Do the removal
for (my $i=0; $i<=$#test_array; $i++) {
    ($test_array[$i] = $test_array[$i]) =~ s{http://}{};
}

### Show the updates
print join(" ", @test_array);

### Output: 
### example.com example.net example.org
```

It works fine, but I'm wondering if there is a more efficient way (either in terms of processing or in terms of less typing). Is there a better way to remove a given string from an array of strings?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need the assignment in this line:

```
($test_array[$i] = $test_array[$i]) =~ s{http://}{};
```

you can just use:

```
$test_array[$i] =~ s{http://}{};
```

For even less typing, take advantage of the `$_` variable:

```
for (@test_array) {
  s{http://}{};
}
```

Comment: Picking this one since it shows how to deal with strings in general. For something that needs the "http://" removal that I was using as my example case, the answer from ikegami is also worth checking out.

Answer (score 6):

When I parse uris, I use [URI](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?URI).

```
use URI qw( );
my @urls = qw( http://example.com:80/ ... );
my @hosts = map { URI->new($_)->host } @urls;
print "@hosts\n";
```

Comment: This is great for the specific case I outlined. I was just using that as an example and am really looking for the generic way to deal with strings in arrays. I should have made that clearer in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the `map` function. It applies an action to every element in an array. You can condense the for-loop into just one line:

```
map s{http://}{}, @test_array;
```

Also, as a side note, an easier way of printing the array contents in space-separated format is to simply put the array inside a double-quoted string:

```
print "@test_array";
```

Comment: Most people cringe at using `map` as a topicalizer. `s{http://}{} for @test_array;` is preferred.

Comment: `map` is meant to be used as a *list operator*. It *maps* one list to another - hence the name. There is no advantage to using it over the ordinary `for`, which avoids misappropriating the concept of a mapping, and results in clearer code.